# Function that is continuous and monotone increasing but not differentiable at 0

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives

Give an example of a function $f: (-1,1) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ which is continuous and monotone increasing, but which is not differentiable at 0. Explain why this does not contradict the fact that if a function is monotone increasing and differentiable at $x_0$ then $f'(x_0) \leq 0$.

My first thought was to use the function $f(x) = |x|$, however I don't believe this function is monotone increasing. Am I right?

Comment: $|x|$ is not monotone increasing, you are correct.

Comment: Make your example monotone increasing by considering $$f(x)=|x|+2x.$$

Comment: I can't propose an edit because it's too small, but shouldn't $f'(x_0) \geq 0$, rather than the other way around?

Answer (score 1):

Write $f(x)=x$ if $x\geq0$ and $f(x)=2x$ if $x<0$.

To make the second conclusion, you would need $f'$ to exist throught the open interval $(-1,1)$, which is obviously not true here.

Comment: Does this still count even though these are two separate functions?

Comment: or should I let $f$ be a piece wise function consisting of the functions you mentioned?

Comment: I have defined $f$ piecewise. So, yes, define $f$ in this way.

Comment: Actually it would only be necessary for f' to exist at 0, not the whole interval.

Comment: +1 Your answer is perfectly fine and I don't know why it originally got no up votes (in my case, I mostly likely didn't see it). In fact, off-hand I can't think of a simpler example for just what was asked.